# Wordpress function - automatically add link to post images

Tags: php, wordpress, image, function, hyperlink

I'd like to add links to all of images in a Wordpress post, linked to the file url and with a 'lightbox' class.

I know that it can be done in the WP admin panel but I don't want to have to select a choice for each picture I upload. I want the links to be added automatically.

So I know the base structure of the function:

```
function lightbox_link($content) {
   ...
}
add_filter('the_content', 'lightbox_link');
```

Anyone can help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: [Simple Lightbox](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-lightbox/) is a pretty good plugin that does this for you automatically.  I've used it on a handful of projects and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Looks promising, I'll test this plugin, thanks a lot guy!

Comment: I tested it but we have to set up links in the admin when we post pictures... It's what I want to avoid using a bespoke function. Any help?